# Married to the Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, marriage

People say the Jewish nation is married to the Torah. Where does it say that? I've heard its a Midrash, a Zohar, and a Gemara in Sanhedrin, but I haven't managed to find them.

(I know we refer to the day of Matan Torah as Yom Chasnuso but that's our marriage to Hashem, not to the Torah.)

Comment: The reference to Sanhedrin is the top of 59a. Rashi there quotes the gemara in Pesachim mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for [Pesachim 49b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=49b&format=pdf):

> תנא רבי חייא כל העוסק בתורה לפני עם הארץ כאילו בועל ארוסתו בפניו שנאמר **תורה צוה לנו משה מורשה אל תקרי מורשה אלא מאורסה**
>
> "Moses gave us the Torah, *morasha*" - don't read "morasha" (inheritance) but "me'orasa" (engaged)

[Shemot Rabba 33:7](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba2/33.htm) has the same reading of *me'orasa* to show the closeness of God and Israel, and alternatively the fact that the Torah is forbidden to idolaters just like a married woman:

> דבר אחר: 
>   מורשה, אל תהי קורא מורשה, אלא מאורסה. 
>   מה חתן זה, כל זמן שלא נשא ארוסתו הוא הוה פראדורין לבית חמיו, משנשאה הרי אביה בא אצלה. 
>   כך עד שלא נתנה תורה לישראל: (שמות יט): ומשה עלה אל האלהים. 
>   משנתנה תורה, אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא למשה: ועשו לי מקדש ושכנתי בתוכם:
>
> דבר אחר: 
>   אל תהי קורא מורשה, אלא מאורסה. מלמד, שהתורה ארוסה לישראל, שנאמר (הושע ב): 
>   וארשתיך לי לעולם. 
>   ומנין שהיא כאשת איש לעובדי כוכבים? 
>   שנאמר (משלי ו): היחתה איש אש בחיקו ובגדיו לא תשרפנה אם יהלך איש על הגחלים ורגליו לא תכוינה כן הבא אל אשת רעהו:

Comment: @Eliyahu Remember that if an answer helped you that you can hit the green check mark.

Comment: @DonielF it's not actually green until you press it...